# Assigning different emitters to different nodes that are randomized

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, constants, skemitternode

I have basic emitter nodes working in my first app. I have created a Constants File that references all nodes throughout my game, and converts them to strings. Great for a mini data base. Its a basic Whack a Mole Game, except I have 12 different characters.

**GameScene Code**

This is called in my `didMoveToView` method:

```
 func star(pos: CGPoint) {
        let emitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "star.sks")
        emitterNode!.particlePosition = pos
        self.addChild(emitterNode!)
        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2), completion:
            {emitterNode!.removeFromParent() })
    }
```

This is called in my `touchesDidBegin` method:

```
if node.name == "charEnemy" {             
    let whackSlot = node.parent!.parent as! WhackSlot
    if !whackSlot.visible { continue }
    if whackSlot.isHit { continue }
    star(touchlocation)
    whackSlot.hit()
    ++score
}
```

I created my own custom class `WhackSlot` to handle the `charEnemy` Node and `charFriend`:

```
let name = Barray[Int((RandomFloat(min: 0.0, max: Float(Barray.count))))]
        charNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: name)
        charNode.name = "charFriend"
        charNode.id = name

    } else {
        charNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: Aarray[Int((RandomFloat(min: 0.0, max: Float(Aarray.count))))])
        charNode.name = "charEnemy"
        charNode.id = ""
    }
```

I created a custom class for `Slot`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class Slot: SKSpriteNode {

    var id:String?
}
```

So it pulls the data from my constants file where the textures have been converted in strings:

```
struct Constants {
    struct DEV {
        static let  DEBUG = false
    }

    struct Zoo {

        struct Animal {

            struct DOG {
              static let  NAME = "dog"
               static let IMAGE = "D1" 
            }
            struct DONKEY {
                static let  NAME = "donkey"
                static let IMAGE = "D2"


            }
            struct CAT {
                static let  NAME = "cat"
                static let IMAGE = "D3"
            }

            static let Zoo = [DOG.IMAGE,DONKEY.IMAGE,CAT.IMAGE]

        }
```

I have it where Image represents a `SKAction` that plays a audio file correlating with my constants file. Instead of just giving Stars at the touch location I would like to have each image have its own emitter.

Things I have tried to this point: Endless tutorials, RW, Cartoon Smart. I have the one emitter working, and I can assign a different emitter to `charFriend` and `charEnemy` yet I can assign each individual animal their own emitter, I tried adding in the Struct Constants, no dice, I tried if-else statements breaking out each image yet `charFriend` supersedes it and the same for `charEnemy`,

This and adding an array of sounds in my Constants for each individual image are my hang ups.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I have hardcoded the game scene, version 2 will be done completely in SpriteKit Scene editor. This is last past of my "Juice" before I submit my first app to App Store. Any guidance would greatly appreciated.

Legacy Eternal.

Latest Software being used.

A little tip I learned a long my journey, if you Make your Game Scene the same size as the Apple TV universal assets @1X optimized for all devices, and for the weird iPad screen just extend your BGNode a little above the parameters and it will automagically convert itself to fit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is nice to think you can have random particles for each SpriteNode, (mine where in a array of images converted into Strings) I found that the best approach is to break out each individual node in the array. This called for creating multiple game scenes, with the nodes, that I wanted to have emitters being represented individually. Particles also eat up a lot performance, so short burst, still look cool, and are effective. adjusting the life time settings, achieved the desired effect.

[image: I decided to use the editor, to see my results in real time.]

It is also really enjoyable to see the type of effects, you can make, and manipulating the ranges in which they reach across the play screen. 
[image: Here is on created making fire, with a smoky effect at the end. Using the alpha scale, to determine how much color, shows and where, as well as how fast the color presents itself.]

my main lesson was to break out the nodes out of the array, and created different logic without ruining the gaming experience.